# How to I use bash to alphabetize entries in a config file, preserving sequential numbering?

Tags: bash, regex, sorting

I have an `.ini` file with this pattern:

```
[Preset0]
Data=78367571EE5E
Data_1=3483290482
Data_2=299230-293
Data_3=2390920391
Name=Mono Lead
Len=3994
[Preset1]
Data=78367571EE5E
Data_1=3483290482
Data_2=299230-293
Data_3=2390920391
Name=Funky Bass
Len=4001
[Preset2]
Data=0200002E3434
Data_1=342EFD340433
Data_2=000000043425
Data_3=EDFE00000000
Name=Airy Pad
Len=3713
```

Each set of data from `[PresetX]` to `Len=X` represents one preset. I want to alphabetize this list by `Name=X`. However, I need the first preset in the file to be `[Preset0]` and I need the presets to remain in numeric order. So, my desired output would be:

```
[Preset0]
Data=0200002E3434
Data_1=342EFD340433
Data_2=000000043425
Data_3=EDFE00000000
Name=Airy Pad
Len=3713
[Preset1]
Data=78367571EE5E
Data_1=3483290482
Data_2=299230-293
Data_3=2390920391
Name=Funky Bass
Len=4001
[Preset2]
Data=78367571EE5E
Data_1=3483290482
Data_2=299230-293
Data_3=2390920391
Name=Mono Lead
Len=3994
```

How would I do this with bash?

Comment: Your example data does not demonstrate that you have a problem. Are the presets already in numeric order? If they are, how can you sort by Name?

Comment: Sorry, the presets are already in numeric order. The names are not in alphabetical order. So I need each preset (Data, Data_1, Data_2, Data_3, Name, Len) to go in alphabetical order, without rearranging the preset numbers.

Comment: Still don't understand. Show more than one complete section and your desired output

Comment: I didn't understand too. If the `Preset` numeric order doesn't match the `Name` alphabetical order, then you must choose one. It seems that the file is already in numeric order of  `Preset`.  Do you want to move the entire `Preset` block to put the blocks in alphabetical order of `Name`?

Comment: Yes Paulo, I want to sort the whole blocks. I have edited my OP to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to sort and increment with `sed`, so this solution mixes `sed`, `bash` and `sort`.

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/\n/|/;/Len=/{s/(.*Name=)(.*)(Len=.*)/\2\1\3/p;d};ba' presets-file |
sort |
while read line; do
    sed -r 's/(.*\|)(\[Preset)[0-9]+(\].*)(Len=.*)/\2'$((i++))'\3\1\4/;s/\|/\n/g' <<<"$line"
done
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I forgot to add that if one of the lines contain a `|` it won't work, because all new lines `\n` of a block are replaced by `|` in the first sed, and in the second sed the `\n` are put back. In this case you should replace it by another 'not occurring' character.